# ¿ Por que se me tarda o demora algunos segundos en ejecutar el codigo en la terminal de Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode, visual, studio

Sera que me podrían arreglar este problema con la terminal de VS Code ? Quiero que por favor me digan como acelerar el tiempo de respuesta del terminal de Vscode. ¡Gracias

Comment: Sin que incluyas el código será dificil que recibas una respuesta útil